# How to create JSON data in JS

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to create a json object such as this that I can send to the server:

```
{
  "email": "some@gmail.com",
  "profile": {
          "token": "test"
  }
}
```

I can create the JSON but don't know how to create one that has multiple objects like the one above. This is what I've done so far

**(In Console)**

```
> var dataModel = { email: "somemail@gmail.com", token: "sometoken"}
>  undefined
> dataModel
>  Object {email: "somemail@gmail.com", token: "sometoken"}
```

The token needs to be inside `profile`

Comment: Should be noted that what you have posted in your top 'code-box' IS JSON. JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a literal way of writing JS objects. The JSON 'string' is essentially a JS object being declared without the `var myVar =` bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create your object as a plain JavaScript object:

```
var object = {
  email: "some@gmail.com",
  profile: {
    token: "test"
  }
}
```

Then convert it to JSON:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(object);
```

Answer (score 2):

Most modern browsers have JSON.stringify(yourData) and JSON.parse(jsonData);

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataModel = {
    email: "somemail@gmail.com",
    profile: {
        token: "sometoken"
    }
};
var dataModelJSON = JSON.stringify(dataModel);
```

Supported by main browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=JSON.stringify

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
var dataModel = { email: "somemail@gmail.com"};
dataModel.profile = {token : "test"}
```

Comment: That will throw an 'undefined' exception.

Comment: Not acquainted with the `{token = "test"}` syntax. Is that something new?

Comment: Nope, not new, now fixed.