# How to Create Inline Embedded Json Data in Datatables

Tags: json, datatables

I can call remote Json resource in DataTables through PHP or plain txt file. But my server has a strict restriction where I generate random HTML file and its json data to be embedded on the html page itself.

I have aready tried:

[I want to create links in record fields in DataTables from JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748262/i-want-to-create-links-in-record-fields-in-datatables-from-json-data)

and

[How to create JSON data in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149556/how-to-create-json-data-in-js)

Since, I need to put convert the remote datasource into inline datasource in single HTML file, how can this be done. I have no issues with inline HTML added.

I wish to replicate the following:

http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html

with inline json data

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../media/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="file:///E:/Downloads/FireFox/DataTables-1.9.4/DataTables-1.9.4/examples/examples_support/jquery.tooltip.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="file:///E:/Downloads/FireFox/DataTables-1.9.4/DataTables-1.9.4/examples_support/jquery-ui-tabs.js"></script> 
  
  
  
<script id="data" type="application/json">
    {
        "sEcho": 1,
  "iTotalRecords": "57",
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": "57",
  "aaData": [
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Other browsers",
      "2": "All others",
      "3": "-",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "U",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Trident",
      "2": "AOL browser (AOL desktop)",
      "3": "Win XP",
      "4": "6",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Camino 1.0",
      "3": "OSX.2+",
      "4": "1.8",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Camino 1.5",
      "3": "OSX.3+",
      "4": "1.8",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Misc",
      "2": "Dillo 0.8",
      "3": "Embedded devices",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "X",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Epiphany 2.20",
      "3": "Gnome",
      "4": "1.8",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Firefox 1.0",
      "3": "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
      "4": "1.7",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Firefox 1.5",
      "3": "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
      "4": "1.8",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Firefox 2.0",
      "3": "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
      "4": "1.8",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Firefox 3.0",
      "3": "Win 2k+ / OSX.3+",
      "4": "1.9",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Misc",
      "2": "IE Mobile",
      "3": "Windows Mobile 6",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "C",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Trident",
      "2": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
      "3": "Win 95+",
      "4": "4",
      "5": "X",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Tasman",
      "2": "Internet Explorer 4.5",
      "3": "Mac OS 8-9",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "X",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Trident",
      "2": "Internet Explorer 5.0",
      "3": "Win 95+",
      "4": "5",
      "5": "C",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Tasman",
      "2": "Internet Explorer 5.1",
      "3": "Mac OS 7.6-9",
      "4": "1",
      "5": "C",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Tasman",
      "2": "Internet Explorer 5.2",
      "3": "Mac OS 8-X",
      "4": "1",
      "5": "C",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Trident",
      "2": "Internet Explorer 5.5",
      "3": "Win 95+",
      "4": "5.5",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Trident",
      "2": "Internet Explorer 6",
      "3": "Win 98+",
      "4": "6",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Trident",
      "2": "Internet Explorer 7",
      "3": "Win XP SP2+",
      "4": "7",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Webkit",
      "2": "iPod Touch / iPhone",
      "3": "iPod",
      "4": "420.1",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "KHTML",
      "2": "Konqureror 3.1",
      "3": "KDE 3.1",
      "4": "3.1",
      "5": "C",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "KHTML",
      "2": "Konqureror 3.3",
      "3": "KDE 3.3",
      "4": "3.3",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "KHTML",
      "2": "Konqureror 3.5",
      "3": "KDE 3.5",
      "4": "3.5",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Misc",
      "2": "Links",
      "3": "Text only",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "X",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Misc",
      "2": "Lynx",
      "3": "Text only",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "X",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Mozilla 1.0",
      "3": "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
      "4": "1",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Mozilla 1.1",
      "3": "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
      "4": "1.1",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Mozilla 1.2",
      "3": "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
      "4": "1.2",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Mozilla 1.3",
      "3": "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
      "4": "1.3",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Mozilla 1.4",
      "3": "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
      "4": "1.4",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Mozilla 1.5",
      "3": "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
      "4": "1.5",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Mozilla 1.6",
      "3": "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
      "4": "1.6",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Mozilla 1.7",
      "3": "Win 98+ / OSX.1+",
      "4": "1.7",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Mozilla 1.8",
      "3": "Win 98+ / OSX.1+",
      "4": "1.8",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Misc",
      "2": "NetFront 3.1",
      "3": "Embedded devices",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "C",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Misc",
      "2": "NetFront 3.4",
      "3": "Embedded devices",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Netscape 7.2",
      "3": "Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2",
      "4": "1.7",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Netscape Browser 8",
      "3": "Win 98SE+",
      "4": "1.7",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Netscape Navigator 9",
      "3": "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
      "4": "1.8",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Presto",
      "2": "Nintendo DS browser",
      "3": "Nintendo DS",
      "4": "8.5",
      "5": "C/A<sup>1</sup>",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Presto",
      "2": "Nokia N800",
      "3": "N800",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Webkit",
      "2": "OmniWeb 5.5",
      "3": "OSX.4+",
      "4": "420",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Presto",
      "2": "Opera 7.0",
      "3": "Win 95+ / OSX.1+",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Presto",
      "2": "Opera 7.5",
      "3": "Win 95+ / OSX.2+",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Presto",
      "2": "Opera 8.0",
      "3": "Win 95+ / OSX.2+",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Presto",
      "2": "Opera 8.5",
      "3": "Win 95+ / OSX.2+",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Presto",
      "2": "Opera 9.0",
      "3": "Win 95+ / OSX.3+",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Presto",
      "2": "Opera 9.2",
      "3": "Win 88+ / OSX.3+",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Presto",
      "2": "Opera 9.5",
      "3": "Win 88+ / OSX.3+",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Presto",
      "2": "Opera for Wii",
      "3": "Wii",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Misc",
      "2": "PSP browser",
      "3": "PSP",
      "4": "-",
      "5": "C",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Webkit",
      "2": "S60",
      "3": "S60",
      "4": "413",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Webkit",
      "2": "Safari 1.2",
      "3": "OSX.3",
      "4": "125.5",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Webkit",
      "2": "Safari 1.3",
      "3": "OSX.3",
      "4": "312.8",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Webkit",
      "2": "Safari 2.0",
      "3": "OSX.4+",
      "4": "419.3",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Webkit",
      "2": "Safari 3.0",
      "3": "OSX.4+",
      "4": "522.1",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    },
    {
      "0": "<img src='details_open.png'>",
      "1": "Gecko",
      "2": "Seamonkey 1.1",
      "3": "Win 98+ / OSX.2+",
      "4": "1.8",
      "5": "A",
      "extra": "hrmll"
    }
  ]
}
</script>   
  
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  



var oTable;
 
/* Formating function for row details */
function fnFormatDetails ( nTr )
{
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
    var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Rendering engine:</td><td>'+aData[2]+' '+aData[5]+'</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Link to source:</td><td>Could provide a link here</td></tr>';
    sOut += '<tr><td>Extra info:</td><td>And any further details here (images etc)</td></tr>';
    sOut += '</table>';
     
    return sOut;
}


 
$(document).ready(function() {


/*** for Tabs April 24th 2014 **/
/*
    $("#tabs").tabs( {
     "show": function(event, ui) {
      var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
      if ( table.length > 0 ) {
       $(table).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
      }
     }
    } );
    
*/
/** **/

    oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
//     "sScrollY": "200px",
//     "bScrollCollapse": true,
     "bPaginate": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
     "bJQueryUI": true,
//      "sDom": '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"iflp<"clear">>',
//      "sDom": 'RC<"clear">lfrtip',
     "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip<"clear spacer">T',
        "bServerSide": false,
        //"sAjaxSource": "scripts/details_col.txt",
  
        "aoColumns": [
     { "mData": "0", "sClass": "center", "bSortable": false},
     { "mData": "1"},
     { "mData": "2"},
     { "mData": "3"},
     { "mData": "4"},
     { "mData": "5"}

/**            {  },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            { "sClass": "center" },
            { "sClass": "center" }
**/
        ],
        "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
     






    $('#example tbody td img').live( 'click', function () {
        var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
        if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr) )
        {
            /* This row is already open - close it */
            this.src = "../examples_support/details_open.png";
            //this.src = "http://l.yimg.com/rz/d/yahoo_news_en-US_s_f_p_168x21_news.png";
            oTable.fnClose( nTr );
        }
        else
        {
            /* Open this row */
            this.src = "../examples_support/details_close.png";
            oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(nTr), 'details' );
        }
    } );


/**** Not Used ****/
/*
    oTable.$('td').hover( function() {
        var iCol = $('td', this.parentNode).index(this) % 5;
        $('td:nth-child('+(iCol+1)+')', oTable.$('tr')).addClass( 'highlighted' );
    }, function() {
        oTable.$('td.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
    } );
*/
/****  ****/



} );









  </script>
```

```css
  <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
   @import "../../media/css/demo_page.css";
   @import "../../media/css/header.ccss";
   @import "../../media/css/demo_table.css";
   @import "../../media/css/demo_table_jui.css";
   @import "../examples_support/jquery.tooltip.css";
   @import "../examples_support/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css";

   thead input { width: 100% }
   input.search_init { color: #999 }

   .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 10px },

  </style>
```

```html
<body id="dt_example" class="ex_highlight">
  <div id="container">
   <div class="full_width big">
    DataTables server-side processing example with hidden row information
   </div>
   
   <h1>Preamble</h1>
   <p>This example shows how you might modify the client-side show/hide details rows example for use with DataTables server-side processing option.</p>
   
   <h1>Live example</h1>
   <div id="dynamic">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th width="4%"></th>
   <th width="25%">Rendering engine</th>
   <th width="20%">Browser</th>
   <th width="25%">Platform(s)</th>
   <th width="16%">Engine version</th>
   <th width="10%">CSS grade</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="5" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>Rendering engine</th>
   <th>Browser</th>
   <th>Platform(s)</th>
   <th>Engine version</th>
   <th>CSS grade</th>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
</table>
   </div>
   
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How precisely do you want to load the content and initialise the dataTable? (== show some code :)

Comment: I'm basically creating the run-time delphi library which would create dynamic htyml page. This html-page would contain the embedded json data. I cannot break a simple html page into CSS and JS dependencies. I would club everything in one page, because my data would anyways be less than 1 MB. Please see: http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html

Answer (score 4):

Extract the content of `<script id="data>..</script>` and convert it to JSON :

```
var data = JSON.parse($("#data").text());

oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
   data : data.aaData,
   ...
})
```

works here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/rvwe28pq/** (updated)

**Update** : Have updated the fiddle so it now works with your code producing child rows too. That should be it. NB: `live()` is deprecated, use `on()` instead.

Comment: I also checked http://jsfiddle.net/timtate/3XbGd/ and thought if we can also give user chance to upload the file together with option to embedd the JSON data. Your solution made my day :)